# How to add a vertical scrollbar to div element only when it overflows using css?

Tags: html, css

i want to add a vertical scrollbar to the div element when more li elements are added to it or in other words when div element overflows.

Below is the html code,

```
<div className="card">
    <form onSubmit={this.handle}>
        <div className="top_content">
            <div className="title">title</div>
            <div className="formats">(.zip)</div>
        </div>
        <div className="content">
            <label>
                <div className="add">
                    <Svg height="17" width="17" />                                    
                </div>
                <input
                    type="file"
                    multiple />
            </label>

            <div className="content_separator">
                <div className="files_list_wrapper">

                    <ul className="files_list">
                        {this.state.files.map((f, index) => (
                             <li key={f.name} className="file_item">
                                 <SvgClose className="icon" height="17" width="17"/>
                                 <span>{f.name}</span>
                             </li>
                         ))}
                     </ul>
                 </div>
             </div>
         </div>
     </form>
 </div>
```

I want the scrollbar for the file_list_wrapper div. how can i do it. could someone help me with it. thanks.

Comment: That's not standard HTML. What is that? You need to tag it.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for `overflow-y: auto`:

```js
let add = document.getElementsByClassName('add')[0];
let list = document.getElementsByClassName('list')[0];

add.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let item = document.createElement('li');
  item.textContent = 'hello';
  list.appendChild(item);
});
```

```css
.list {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px black;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<button class="add">Add item</button>
<ol class="list"></ol>
```